# laravel file uploading customname

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my controller to upload a image to mysql and it has to take imge->id , and image->name attributes to store in db.

```
use App\FileUpload;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    class FileUploadController extends Controller
    {
        public function showUploadForm(){
          return view('upload.upload');
        }
        public function store(Request $request){
            if($request->hasFile('file')){
                //$imgFullname = new FileUpload;
                $imgFullname= $file->id . '.' . $file->name. '.'
                $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->file->storeAs('public/upload', $imgFullname);
                $file = new FileUpload;
                $file->name = $fileName;
                $file->save();
                //return 'yes';
            }


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yElHA.png)

Comment: Format the question so that we can understand well. @Sekhar

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `;` at end of line:

```
use App\FileUpload;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    class FileUploadController extends Controller
    {
        public function showUploadForm(){
          return view('upload.upload');
        }
        public function store(Request $request){
            if($request->hasFile('file')){
                //$imgFullname = new FileUpload;
                $imgFullname= $file->id . '.' . $file->name. '.'; //<---- add ; here
                $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->file->storeAs('public/upload', $imgFullname);
                $file = new FileUpload;
                $file->name = $fileName;
                $file->save();
                //return 'yes';
            }


}
```